# Expanding partition - Ubuntu server on QNAP VM

Tags: partitioning

I run Ubuntu Server under Virtual Station on my QNAP NAS. I recently allocated more space to the virtual disk and incorrectly assumed that it would expand automagically.

How do I expand the partition to use up the increased free space? As it's a virtual server, I don't really have the option to boot of a USB live stick as such.

Comment: You do, I am using Virtualbox and to expand my disk I will add `gparted ISO` to the __virtual device optical drive from settings menu for that VM__ then boot and simply follow the onscreen instructions to expand the disk space. I am thinking there should be a similar settings for _Virtual Station_. Remember to __unlock the disk__ when in gprated so you can expand.

Comment: So something like boot of a live Ubuntu image and run gpart would work?

Comment: No you you add `gparted ISO` to the `virtual optical optical drive of the VM` then launch the VM and gparted will be booted instead then you will be presented with the partitions then you do the expansion there,  but note the empty space needs to  beside the target partition for it to work.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://www.qnap.com/en/qa/con_show.php?op=showone&cid=185). The example I give are for Virtual box.

Comment: OK, I think I'm almost there. I can now see the additional space from within Ubuntu server but I still can't allocate it: ─

vda5                 LVM2_member 149.5G
  ├─ASGUARD--vg-root   ext4         98.5G /
  └─ASGUARD--vg-swap_1 swap            1G [SWAP]

Comment: Please add an image of the `gparted screen` so I can advice further.

Comment: @George, here you go: http://imgur.com/a/beLzb

Comment: Sorry been busy, will get back to you let me check something!

Comment: Ok lets try this, right click on the extended partition to __deactivate it__ then resize the __sda5__ partition.

Comment: sda5 or vda5? I'll try tonight but from memory it doesn't let me deactivate that extended partition. It only lets me deactivate the lvm2 one which in turn deactivates that extended one.

Comment: Sorry `vda` and if the target partitions gets deactivated go ahead and add the space you want

Comment: Yes your right __de-activate__ vda5 then go head with the increase.

Comment: OK, nothing to expand. If you look at the pic, VDA5 partition is already showing taking up the full space in VDA2

Comment: where is the __pic__ did you remove it?

Comment: No it's still there https://i.imgur.com/YxdmuwY.png

Comment: The 50GB, is that the added space?

Comment: Yes and it shows here but not in the OS when booted

Comment: Any other suggestions I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues.  This post helped fix it.

https://superuser.com/questions/917988/gparted-cannot-resize-extended-or-lvm-partition

Basically, Increase Storage in QNAP VM Manager settings (Ubuntu knows nothing about this bit yet).  Get hold of GPARTED from https://gparted.org/download.php and attach as a CD to the Virtual VM settings.

*** BACKUP YOUR VM IN CASE THE NEXT STEPS GO WRONG ***

Change boot order so CD gets booted.

Boot - This starts GPARTED.

Unlock (Deactivate) the LV partition you want to extend, if necessary.  Extend into the Unallocated space.  Apply and then shutdown.

Change boot order in QNAP VM so Disk gets booted.  Then follow post above with lvdisplay, vgs, lvextend and resize2fs commands.  Reboot.